# Why are Java 9 and 10 invisible?

Tags: java, version

I needed to install Java on my new computer, so like almost everyone I guess, I searched for "java" on my favorite search engine, and found the java.com download page. This one offers to download Java 8 update 171. But I know the latest version of Java is 10, and between 8 and 10, there's 9 (I'm clever, I know). I realized that on my old computers, I've always had Java 8 and I've never been asked to update it to 9 or 10. Then I looked for the SDK, and same thing, Google leads me to the SDK 8 download page.

On the french Wikipedia page about Java, versions 9 and 10 are not event listed in the history.
On the english version, I can read that :

> The current and only long-term-support (LTS) version is Java 8

What does it mean, and why 8 ?

Then :

> Java 9 is no longer supported, so Oracle advises its users to "immediately transition" to Java 10

Oh okay, but what about 8 if 9 is no longer supported ?

I'd like to understand all that, if someone can help me...

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It means that Java 8 is currently still supported, and that Java 9 is not supported.  If I read correctly, Oracle is telling us that once Java 8 gets twilighted, users should immediately switch to Java 10 and skip Java 9.

Comment: Ah I was wrong: you can find more about LTS here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/eol-135779.html

Comment: You want to search for the JDK, not just Java or SDK, and you always want to download it from Oracle, not java.com. [JDK 10](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk10-downloads-4416644.html), [JDK 11 early access](http://jdk.java.net/11/)

Comment: @GotoFinal This page confuses me even more because they plan to end Public Updates for Java 8 in 2020 and for Java 10 in 2018... Why is that ?
My question is definetly not "how to download JDK 10"...

Comment: @Harlan do you know the "long term support" term? it means that some releases are supported longer - so people can use them on important services without thinking about updating to major releases ech few months. And now (from java 8) oracle wants to release one major java release each 6 months, and support them only for that 6 months. So sometimes they will release LTS versions that will be supported for much longer, so if you need stable java you can only upgrade from LTS updates each 3 years (or even more) instead of each 6 months.

Comment: Thank you for this clear answer. I understand now !

Comment: @GotoFinal Can you post this as an answer so I can mark the question as resolved ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After java 8 oracle decided to release new java version each 6 months, but they can't then support like 10 different java versions at once so like many other companies with such release cycles (also look how most of popular linux distributions are released) they are releasing some of versions as LTS (long term support) versions.
As we can read on http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/eol-135779.html oracle decided to release LTS each 3 years starting from Java 11 (that will be released in September 2018 and will be supported for 5 years + 3 extended), normal releases are only supported for that 6 months when they are used.
Java 8 as last release before this change is also considered as LTS so it is supported for longer period of time too.

This allows fast adopting users and companies to use new features quickly instead of waiting few years just to get that one feature they want, and companies/users that want something more stable that would not break in few next years can just use LTS versions.

Answer (score 0):

I just searched "Java 10 download" and found [this link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk10-downloads-4416644.html) to download Java 10

However, Java 8 is still the recommended version per [this page](https://java.com/en/download/win10.jsp).

Comment: Okay but I try to put myself in a basic user's shoes. Imagine they want to use an app that requires Java, they would just look for Java (well a lot of people would be stuck before that), not caring or knowing about versions, then they are invited to download 8. Why would Oracle recommend an "old" version ?

Comment: It's currently in version 10.0.1, so maybe Java 10 hasn't been optimized yet? Either way if you're not sure I would highly recommend following Oracle's suggestions